# Visual Studio and Class Files not in Solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have some class files (.vb or .cs it doesn't really matter either way) that aren't in a solution. When I do things like remove function parameters, it won't flag up uses of the no-longer-present parameters or any other error for that matter yet it can figure out how to highlight the code.

It does fine for .aspx files.

Can it be made to highlight errors in class files that don't belong to a solution?

Comment: If it is not a solution then it won't get compiled so you won't get errors.  The simple workaround is to add the project that uses the source file to your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is not a solution then it won't get compiled so you won't get
>   errors. The simple workaround is to add the project that uses the
>   source file to your solution.

Hans Passant